# React Router Dom 5 - download static files from IIS Server. How to configure file web.config?

Tags: reactjs, iis, react-router-dom

React application is located in the same directory as the download files.

https://some-url.com/ - App with React-router-dom 5
https://some-url.com/files/ - directory with static files, located on the server.
Sometimes the router does not have time to process the address and gets a 404 error and the file won't download. ( Because of cache or something)

How to configure **web.config** server file so that you can download files from a folder **site.com/files/** ?

**web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Assets" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="([\S]+[.](html|htm|svg|js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Try using FRT to view details about the 404 error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: It occurred to me that you need to check if the IIS installation feature has a feature called "Static Content" enabled. The "static content" service is responsible for serving the Static contents like images, scripts , style sheets file, .... It's a feature that must be explicitly enabled on the server. If you have installed it, please enable HTTP Detailed Errors in IIS to see what the sub-status code of the 404 error is?